# Best way to merge objects using key in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

What the best way to merge objects in an array using a key?

```
[
   {
      "refr": "https://example.com/",
      "transactions": 1
   },
   {
      "refr": null,
      "pageviews": 1
   },
   {
      "refr": "https://example.com/",
      "pageviews": 1
   }
]
```

Desired Result using 'refr' key:

```
[
   {
      "refr": "https://example.com/",
      "transactions": 1,
      "pageviews": 1
   },
   {
      "refr": null,
      "pageviews": 1
   },   
]
```

I am looking for a solution that does NOT use any third party tools, like lodash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can group values by the `refr` key.

```js
const input = [
   {
      "refr": "https://example.com/",
      "transactions": 1
   },
   {
      "refr": null,
      "pageviews": 1
   },
   {
      "refr": "https://example.com/",
      "pageviews": 1
   }
];

const groupByRefr = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.refr] ? acc[cur.refr] = { ...acc[cur.refr], ...cur } : acc[cur.refr] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(groupByRefr);
console.log(result);
```